# Reveal Transition animation

Tags: java, android, animation

Is it possible  To add reveal transition animation for android version 4.4 or less.I have to do something like reveal transition animation in lolipop version but unable to do that.Please help.Thanks in advance.!!

Comment: try this you may get your ans from this link : https://github.com/ferdy182/Android-CircularRevealFragment

Comment: Thanku but i already tried that but its reqiures API level 21 and i have to do this type of animation for API level 19 or below not for Lolipop..!! Need more Help..!! @AmitPrajapati

Comment: You should use android-support-v7-appcompat for this the older version support